# Scrapy next href with rel="next"

Tags: scrapy

on the Scrapy example i found this line

```html
 next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

Now i wan't select the first 
So i will extract the first link where have a 'rel="next"' on it.

I try it with

```html
next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a[@rel="next"] ::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

But its dont work.

How i can do that?

Thanks

Joni

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are combining `css` selector with `xpath` selectors.

with css:

```
'a[rel="next"]::attr(href)'
```

with xpath

```
'//a[@rel="next"]/@href'
```